# Select query - Fetch all data between two age min and max age

Tags: mysql

Mind burning query for me.
I want to fetch the all  record between two age condition. Any one please help me. My query is write below

```
SELECT tbl_trip.* FROM tbl_trip  WHERE  ((tbl_trip.minage >= '15' AND tbl_trip.maxage <= '15') OR (tbl_trip.maxage <= '28' AND tbl_trip.minage >= '28'))
```

In this query i want all record from database .. where age lie between 15 to 28 . In this all reords get, e.g. minage to maxage : 1 to 16,12 to 30 , 16 to 24, 27 to 28 But not get like 3 to 13 or 29 or 100 . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your logic is quite unclear.  Please edit your existing question.  Place some sample data of applicable columns, then show a sample of what you want your expected output to be.  Another sample of an age breakdown I have at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154058/mysql-group-by-multiple-rows/10154196#10154196 and dont know if that might clarify both sample data and desired ouput.

Comment: As you given e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154058/mysql-group-by-multiple-rows/10154196#10154196 . Its not working for me. I have already test it. As my question i want All records of age range from 14 to 28 . . In this Range 1 to 16,12 to 30 , 16 to 24, 27 to 28 But not get like 3 to 13 or 29 or 100(Becoz no age lie between my range) @DRapp

Comment: Again, please edit your question.  Show YOUR sample existing data that shows whatever age gaps of the individual records, then show what you want the FINAL return result set based on the sample data you provide.  Your age ranges overlap each other and don't make sense such as 1 to 16, then 12 to 30... in this case why are you including 12-30 should that not be 17-30 since 1-16 would already cover the 12-16 anyhow?  Hence the confusion / lack of clarity of your question without context data to work with.

Comment: Thanks @DRapp .. I got my sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query checks your given range between minage and maxage, and vice versa.

```
select * from tbl_trip 
where (((minage>=15 and minage<=22) or (maxage>=15 and maxage<=22))
or((15>=minage and 15<=maxage) or (22<=maxage and 22>=minage)))
```

This is also working, Please check it properly before you use:

```
select * from tbl_trip 
where ((minage>=12 and minage<=22) or (maxage>=12 and maxage<=22))
       or ((12>=minage and 22<=maxage))
```

Here is **another way**:

```
select * from tbl_trip
Where GREATEST(GREATEST(minage,12)-LEAST(maxage,22),0)=0
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. i will give feedback in some time.

Comment: select * from tbl_trip
Where GREATEST(GREATEST(minage,12)-LEAST(maxage,22),0)=0 this query working fine for me.. Dear @rohit

Answer (score 3):

Here is the right way Rohit wrote a confusing Query.

```
select * from tbl_trip where ((minage>=12 and minage<=22) or (maxage>=12 and maxage<=22)) or ((minage<=12 and maxage>=22))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you need to get all the records from the DB where minage--maxage range intersects with the given one. Hereinafter the given range will be from X to Y, the row's range will be from A to B. Obviously, Y > X, B > A.

There are Three situations in which these ranges cross:

A--B is completely inside X--Y. That means that on the numeric line these numbers lie like this: A, X--Y, B. Therefore, the condition is

> A <=X **and** B >= Y

A--B patially crosses the X--Y on the **left** side of X--Y. On the numeric line these numbers look like: A, X, B, Y. Therefore, the condition is

> A <= X **and** X <= B **and** B <= Y

Same for A--B crossing the X--Y range on it's **right** side. Numeric line: X, A, Y, B. Condition:

> X <= A **and** A <= Y **and** Y <= B
>   
>   In conclusion, the final condition is:
>
> (A <= X && B >= Y) || (A <= X && X <= B && B <= Y) || (X <= A && A <= Y && Y<= B)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Please explain it by query.

Answer (score 2):

Try with it, its working fine for me

```
select * from tbl_trip
Where GREATEST(GREATEST(minage,12)-LEAST(maxage,22),0)=0
```